i`m trying to integrate my flutter app with square company, to make payments, some one can help me with some documents or implementation?
I'm having trouble making a payment after creating a card token. I don't know how I can complete the payment. I already have the token, but how can I pass the amount so that Square receives the amount.
I tried using a URL directly, as I found in the documentation, but it didn't work. Sometimes I can't get my method to return a response from Square. If anyone has any implementation code, it would help me a lot.
my code:
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:square_in_app_payments/models.dart';
import 'package:square_in_app_payments/in_app_payments.dart';
import 'package:ticketshow/util/app_config.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class CardPaymentScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardPaymentScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<CardPaymentScreen> createState() => _CardPaymentScreenState();
}

class _CardPaymentScreenState extends State<CardPaymentScreen> {
  void _pay() {
    InAppPayments.setSquareApplicationId(AppConfig.getSquareApplicationId());
    InAppPayments.startCardEntryFlow(
        onCardNonceRequestSuccess: _onCardNonceRequestSuccess,
        onCardEntryCancel: _onCardEntryCancel);
  }

  Future<void> _onCardNonceRequestSuccess(CardDetails cardResult) async {
    print(cardResult.nonce);

    try {
      var response = await InAppPayments.startSecureRemoteCommerce(
        amount: 1000,
        onMaterCardNonceRequestSuccess: (nonceDetails) {
          // Handle success
          print('Payment successful: ${nonceDetails}');
          InAppPayments.completeCardEntry(
              onCardEntryComplete: () => print('Payment complete!'));
        },
        onMasterCardNonceRequestFailure: (error) {
          // Handle failure
          print('Payment failed: $error');
          InAppPayments.showCardNonceProcessingError(error.toString());
        },
      );
      print(response);
    } catch (error) {
      InAppPayments.showCardNonceProcessingError(error.toString());
      print("$error");
    }

    InAppPayments.completeCardEntry(onCardEntryComplete: () => print('yey'));
  }

  void _onCardEntryComplete() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Pagamento Completo'),
          content: const Text('Seu pagamento foi processado com sucesso.'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _onCardEntryCancel() {
    print("Cancelado pelo usuário");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Pagamento com Cartão"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _pay,
          child: Text("Iniciar Pagamento"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

